# Bad event binding in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-events

I did sorting and searching data row on a data-table. Also, when clicking on data-row, it alerts its name and code of data-row. Someone gave a comment on my code: "the event binding is bad and weak!". I got this comment in an interview so I didn't get the chance to ask why. I hope someone can figure out what the problem is.

```
<!--HTML-->
<table class="" id="tabCountryList">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="" tabindex="">Name</th>
            <th class="" tabindex="">Code</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbCountryListContent">       
    </tbody>
</table>

<!--javascript-->
var tbContent="";
for(var idx in countries){
    tbContent+="<tr class='countryRow'><td>"+countries[idx].name+"</td>      
    <td>"+countries[idx].code+"</td></tr>";
}
document.getElementById("tbCountryListContent").innerHTML=tbContent;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tabCountryList").DataTable({"responsive": true, "dom":     
    '<"toolbar">frtip',"displayLength": 4 ,"aaSorting": []});
    $(".countryRow").click(function() {
        var tempObj = $(this).find("td");
        alert(tempObj[0].innerHTML);    
    });
    $(".toolbar").hide();
});
```

Here is the resulting image:

[image: The image of result]

Comment: you can use `jquery` `on` method instead of direct. may be it was an issue.e.g `$(".class").on("click",function(){});` instead of `$(".class").click(function(){});`

Comment: Thank you for this hint.